Thingsboard custom aggregation function
I have a problem where I would like more control over the date range and returned telemetry.  For example: I need to return all telemetry values within a time slice of 9am-10am across a date range.  The issue is that there is no apparent way to filter the information without creating custom widgets to replace all of the built in ones, so that they accept separate API calls.
In theory time slicing on historical telemetry could be done if there was the ability to create a custom aggregation function.
Then the aggregation function could be linked and controlled by a widget on the dashboard, in order to filter telemetry by timestamps.
I tried the filter function and it only works with latest values, so historical telemetry cannot be filtered in this way.
I have seen a number of posts that would love to have more control of the returned information via time of day ranges and not just from one date to another.  The ability to create a custom aggregation function could solve this issue.
